# Send a formatted email without html

Tags: python, html, email, smtp, mime

I have a problem. I want to send a formatted email without html. Is there an option to send a formatted email with Python without `html` ?

For example, on GMail, if I want to write a message, I can format it within GMail. But it is not displayed as HTML.
The problem is that with HTML, often the messages are not displayed directly, unlike when I format them directly.

You can format your mail e.g. [image]

What I want:

---

[image]

---

```py
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "your@email.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I tried

```py
class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

print(color.BOLD + 'Hello World !' + color.END)

[E-Mail Output]
[1m Hello World [0mwie
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatting GMail is applying is actually HTML under the hood. For example, if you bold some text, that text is actually being wrapped in a `<b></b>` tag. Instead of displaying the raw HTML, GMail's compose email window is using that HTML to render the formatting, in much the way that a browser will render HTML instead of displaying raw HTML.

The Python interpreter itself doesn't have a way to render HTML in this way. Some other software would be needed, such as an IDE or text editor, that could generate HTML tags from a user-friendly UI. This generated HTML could then be copy-pasted into your python file.

One way to generate this HTML would be to compose your email in GMail, open the inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I), use the selector to highlight the body of the compose email window, right-click on the parent element, and then select Copy > Inner HTML from the right-click context menu. (This flow is based on Firefox; other browsers may vary)

Comment: For example, if I copy the content from GMail and send it by e-mail, it works in exactly the same way as with my HTML. 
The problem is that not all e-mail providers display this "copied HTML" correctly. Either I have misunderstood and you need to show a small example.

Comment: `<div><font size="6" style="">This </font>is<font color="#00ff00" style=""> a</font> <b style="">test</b></div>`

Comment: These days email bodies are either sent as plain text or as HTML. If there is formatting, it is sent as HTML.  

I had interpreted that your issue was with writing the HTML, not that the received HTML is not displaying correctly. The GMail suggestion was for an easy way to create the HTML without manually writing it. Perhaps the issue with your copied HTML is that you need to wrap it in <html> and <body> tags? (see next comment). Testing locally, your HTML snippet works as-is for my email client.

Comment: `body = '<html><body><div><font size="6" style="">This </font>is<font color="#00ff00" style=""> a</font> <b style="">test</b></div></body></html>' msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))`

Comment: Well, that is actually like my example. That does not work.

Comment: This may be an issue with the email client receiving the email rather than your script. Perhaps there's a setting that needs to be changed.... Does it otherwise display html emails from other sources properly? Which email client are you using to receive your emails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247179/discussion-between-jonathanfuchs-and-test).

Answer (score 0):

[Rich-Text Format (RTF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format/) is another option. Microsoft Outlook has an option to compose a message in RTF, which may be saved as a file with extension .rtf. The format uses a markup code that employs '{' and '}' style brackets, and unique formatting codes, and not HTML and CSS. Here is a link to a resource that discusses the syntax: [Basics of Rich Text Format (RTF)](https://iq.opengenus.org/rich-text-format/#code_syn/)

I expect Python has access to RTF edit controls (i.e., text boxes for placement on a form); creating a message, then copying it to the RTF control, and setting the various properties you are seeking through the control, may be a fast way to generate the syntax.

Comment: Not sure RTF works universally. I think it's just an Outlook thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use win32 library and it should look like this.

```
import win32com.client as win32

olApp =win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNS=olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
mailItem= olApp.CreateItem(0)
mailItem.Subject="Hello my friend2"
mailItem.BodyFormat=1
mailItem.Body="Hellooooo"
mailItem.To="emailaddress@email.com"
mailItem._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209,0,8,0,olNS.Accounts.Item("emailaddress@email.com")))
mailItem.Display()
mailItem.Save()
mailItem.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format your email for HTML by using `messageObject.subtype == 'html'` It will send your email as you formatted it in the first place.

For more information, go to the end of [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) page. And also check the sixth example from [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples) official page

Comment: Could you please explain this in more detail? And best of all with a minium runnable program

Comment: Are you using Simple Python or Any framework?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: Are you using any python framework or just sending the email through a simple python script?

Comment: Just a simple python script

Comment: @Test Updated the answer, please check. Thanks.